# How to rewrite nested subqueries inside in statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query with nested subqueries inside `in`. Does anyone have a better/shorter way of rewriting this query:

```
select *
  from Table1 t1
 where t1.column1 in (select t21.column1
                        from Table2 t21
                       where t21.column2 in (select t31.column2
                                               from Table3 t31
                                              where t31.column3 = 'Value1'))
   and t1.column1 in (select t22.column1
                        from Table2 t22
                       where t22.column2 in (select t32.column2
                                               from Table3 t32
                                              where t32.column3 = 'Value2'))
```

Notice that the inner most subquery has different values in the `where` condition.

---

**EDIT:**
I've got good responses but I haven't got any simplified form that meets my need or haven't been able to infer from the answers. I guess I wasn't clear enough on my requirements. I can put a join in the two inner subqueries and get what I need. So, now the question is if the following query can be compressed further in a readable way:

```
select *
  from Table1 t1
 where t1.column1 in (select t21.column1
                        from Table2 t21
                               join
                             Table3 t31
                               on t21.column2 = t31.column2
                       where t31.column3 = 'Value1'))
   and t1.column1 in (select t21.column1
                        from Table2 t21
                               join
                             Table3 t31
                               on t21.column2 = t31.column2
                       where t31.column3 = 'Value2'))
```

Comment: IN ('Value1', 'Value2') will not fetch correct result for me. I need intersection. I need values from Table1 which has related value containing both Value1 and Value2 in Table3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Expanding algebraically:**

```
If {X} =>
    select *
    from Table1
    where column1 in ({A})
      and column1 in ({B})

Then {X} =>
    select *
    from Table1
    where column1 in ({A} INTERSECT {B})
-----------------------------------------
If {A} =>
    select column1
    from Table2
    where column2 in ({C})

And {B} =>
    select column1
    from Table2
    where column2 in ({D})

Then {A} INTERSECT {B} =>
    select column1
    from Table2
    where column2 in ({C} INTERSECT {D})
-----------------------------------------
If {C} =>
    select column2
    from Table3
    where column3 = 'Value1'

And {D} =>
    select column2
    from Table3
    where column3 = 'Value2'

Then {C} INTERSECT {D} =>
    select column2
    from Table3
    where column3 IN ('Value1','Value2')
    group by column2
    having count(distinct column3) = 2
-----------------------------------------
```

**Substituting back:**

```
select *
from Table1 t1
where t1.column1 in (select t2.column1
                     from Table2 t2
                     where t2.column2 in (select t3.column2
                                          from Table3 t3
                                          where t3.column3 IN ('Value1','Value2')
                                          group by t3.column2
                                          having count(distinct t3.column3) = 2)
```

**Compacting:**

```
select *
from Table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from Table2 t2
              where t2.column1 = t1.column1
                and exists (select 1
                            from Table3 t3
                            where t3.column2 = t2.column2
                              and t3.column3 IN ('Value1','Value2')
                            group by t3.column2
                            having count(distinct t3.column3) = 2)
```

You can continue rewriting, changing the `exists` to `inner joins`, but that won't change the query plan.

Comment: When having clause is defined it is not pulling any data. Distinct count is returning 1.

Comment: Then your example code doesn't accurately model your actual query.  Double check your typing or post your real query & sample data.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should be able to use `INNER JOIN`s for this, although this is untested so I could be totally off.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.column2 = t3.column2
WHERE t3.column3 IN ('Value1', 'Value2')
```

**Edit:**

Re the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295196/how-to-rewrite-nested-subqueries-inside-in-statements/25295283?noredirect=1#comment39423210_25295196), I think you might actually need something more like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
WHERE t2.column2 IN (SELECT t3.column2
                     FROM Table3 t3
                     WHERE t3.column3 = 'Value1'
      AND t2.column2 IN (SELECT t3.column2
                         FROM Table3 t3
                         WHERE t3.column3 = 'Value2'
```

It isn't quite as nice, but I think that's what you need to do to handle that `AND` case.

**Edit 2:**

Or better yet, this could be complete nonsense, but something along these lines:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3a ON t2.column2 = t3a.column2
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3b ON t2.column2 = t3b.column2
WHERE (t3a.column3 = 'Value1' AND t3b.column3 = 'Value2') OR
      (t3a.column3 = 'Value2' AND t3b.column3 = 'Value1')
```

I'm not totally sure if you need the last line or not.

Comment: Oh, I was just thinking about the same, but it is possible you need a `LEFT JOIN` instead of inner join. Not  too sure though.

Comment: How are you dealing with fanning from the joins?  This could return a *much* larger result set than the OP's query, depending on what's in Table2

Comment: I can use join in the two inner subqueries and get my correct resultset. I have updated my question. You edit after referring to the comments has been the closest one yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t21.column2 = t31.column2
WHERE t31.column3 IN ('Value1', 'Value2')
```

test around, you may want to change it to `INNER JOIN`

Comment: No need to use `LEFT JOIN` if you are filtering by a column from `Table3`, you can just use `INNER JOIN`

Comment: This does not return my required result set. I need records from Table1.column1 which are included in join of Table2 and Table3 having values of both Value1 and Value2. Refer to my edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

These could be converted to joins. Maybe something like:

```
select     Table1.Column1, Table1.Column2, Table1.Column3--and so forth
from       Table1
inner join Table2
    on     Table2.Column1 = Table1.Column1
inner join Table3
    on     Table3.Column2 = Table2.Column2
    and    Table3.Column3 in ('Value1','Value2')
group by   Table1.Column1, Table1.Column2, Table1.Column3
having     COUNT(distinct Table3.Column3)>=2
```

Update:
I'm seeing other examples that are coming close, but just using "...Column3 in..." won't quite cut it. In the original question, Table1.Column1 has to be linked to BOTH 'Value1' and 'Value2' because that's how AND works.

Answer (score 0):

is this equivalent?

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
            t2.column1
        FROM 
            Table2 t2 INNER  JOIN
            Table3 t3  ON 
            t2.column2 = t3.column2 AND 
            t3.column3 = 'Value1'
    ) v1 ON
    t1.column1 = v1.column1 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
            t2.column1
        FROM 
            Table2 t2 INNER JOIN
            Table3 t3 ON
            t2.column2 = t3.column2 AND 
            t3.column3 = 'Value2'
    ) v2 ON
    t1.column1 = v2.column1
```

or

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            t2.column1
    FROM 
            Table2 t2 INNER  JOIN
            Table3 t3  ON 
            t2.column2 = t3.column2 AND 
            t3.column3 = 'Value1' INNER  JOIN
            Table3 t4  ON 
            t2.column2 = t4.column2 AND 
            t4.column3 = 'Value2'
    ) v ON
    t1.column1 = v.column1
```

not sure if you need the `distinct`.

sample data would help us test

Comment: Second option is does not return any records. First option is close. I'm still getting one record which has Value1 but does not have a record with Value2. I have not built the sample data yet, when I get time I'll link it up with sql fiddle.

Comment: sry, should have aliased 2nd t3 differently.  if you tested and implemented it, the compiler would have caught it